# Removing Trailing Dot in Figure Caption

Tags: floats, captions, subcaption, report

How do I remove trailing dot in Figure Captions. I am getting
Fig. 1.1. but I require it as Fig. 1.1

I have seeing solutions for other classes of document(Scrreport).I am using report class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the option **labelsep** of the package [caption](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) with the value **none** or **quad** (for a white space)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[labelsep=quad]{caption}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        Include graphic here
        \caption{This is the caption}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I tried your suggestion but its not having any effect.

Comment: Strange. Could you add a mwe in your first post in order to help capturing the problem ?

Comment: The method you suggested is correct. I had used another line in my style package    \RequirePackage[compact]{titlesec}
  \captionsetup{labelsep=period}
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} which the method you suggested not to work.